# How to Apply Interpolation to Mesh casted Shadow

Tags: mesh, lighting, shadows, toon-shading

I have a simple question, you know how there is a way using color ramp on the texture to make the color sharp (Setting the Constant on ColorRamp) i wonder is there a way to do that same with the shadow that is casted by mesh in light and also be seen in vieport

Answer (score 1):

In Eevee, turn on Soft Shadows and have a light with a radius to cause the soft shadows.

[image]

In the compositor, add a ColourRamp between the shadow pass and Exposure Node.

[image]